# How can the application name be changed in Linux?

Tags: ubuntu, rename

Can we custom change the name of an application before launching it in Linux?

Suppose the title bar shows name of the application as "Mozilla Firefox", can it be renamed to "Browser?"

Comment: What distribution, what window manager?

Comment: And are there specific applications you are having issues with?

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the desktop shortcut (for instance, `/usr/share/applications/firefox-esr.desktop`) to your `$HOME/.local/share/applications/` folder, and edit it there.

You can also customize it in other ways; for instance you can add additional sections like `[Desktop Action FOO]` sections that are visible when you right-click on the launcher icon:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Firefox ESR
Comment=Browse the World Wide Web
GenericName=Web Browser
Exec=/usr/lib/firefox-esr/firefox-esr %u
Type=Application
Icon=firefox-esr
Categories=Network;WebBrowser;
...
Actions=new-private-window;FOO;BAR

[Desktop Action new-private-window]
Name=Open a New Private Window
Exec=/usr/lib/firefox-esr/firefox-esr --private-window
StartupWMClass=Firefox-esr
StartupNotify=true

[Desktop Action FOO]
Name=Open profile FOO
Exec=/usr/lib/firefox-esr/firefox-esr -P FOO

[Desktop Action BAR]
Name=Open profile BAR
Exec=/usr/lib/firefox-esr/firefox-esr -P BAR
```